# Want to get authorization to multiple accounts at once

Tags: spotify

Okay so I just got started setting up my spotify developer account and getting my application registered and am now going through the basics of the Spotify Web API. Now I have a specific thing I want to be able to do with the application (if it's possible). 
I want to essentially be able to access two accounts at once and use user-library-read on one account and then use user-library-modify on another to essentially copy over all of the tracks from one account to another.

So going through and reading the documentation on some the process of authenticating a spotify account from a user to gain access, I understand the basic process, but is there a way to do this twice for two separate accounts like say on the login page I have two separate logins. One will be for the account that you want to get the songs from and the other account will be the one that you want to add the songs to and I could just use different scopes for each one. Or would something like storing all of the track_id's into a list then iterating through it and modifying the other accounts library work?

So basically, how do I authenticate two accounts at once using different scopes for each to allow a user to ready info from one account and copy over what was read to another.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you propose is the right thing to do. You don't login to two accounts twice. You just ask for access token with whatver scopes you want, which can be different, and then exchange them appropriately on each call to the API.